# Why do I get a "command not found" error from this script?

Tags: linux, shell

I'm trying to run this script:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

#shell script to find average of N number

echo "enter the size(N)"
read N
sum=0
echo "enter the numbers"
for ((i =1;i<=N; i++))

do
read n
sum=$((sum+n))
done

avg=$(echo $sum/$N | bc -l)

echo $avg
```

But I get an error:

```
i/shell.sh:line 18: bc: command not found.
```

Why is that?

Comment: You don't have `bc` installed, or at least no available in your `PATH`.

Comment: What platform is this? Unless you've broken your PATH variable, I would expect it to be an embedded system (an Android device, etc) to not have `bc` installed, as `bc` [is POSIX-standardized](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/bc.html#tag_20_09).

Comment: Line 18 is `echo $avg`. Did you modify anyhting in the script before posting it?

Comment: @amilakrishan : You did not post, which OS you are using.

Answer (score 0):

The `bc` executable isn't found in the `$PATH` of the user that's executing it. If it's installed, make sure it's in the `$PATH`, e.g.:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin
```

If it isn't, you'll have to install it first.

Comment: `/usr/bin`, not `/usr/bin/bc`, needs to be in the `PATH`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy yikes! Indeed! Momentary concentration lapse... Thanks for noticing. Edited and fixed.

Comment: Since we see from the `#!` line, that i.e. `bash` is found in `bin`, wouldn't it be a safer bet to put `/bin` into the PATH instead of `/usr/bin`? Just in case the OP is on a platform where these two are not identical.